# Low disk space on <<filesystem root>>

Tags: partitioning, directory, root, 17.04, home-directory

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 (installed in May over Windows 10) and today I suddenly found my laptop too slow, so I did a BleachBit clean.
Nothing better happened, then Ubuntu told me my filesystem is full.
I was: "WTF? I have about 800GB free!", so I took a look to the situation:
[image: Here is my only partition]

Then I opened "Disk usage analyzer" and I found this:

[image: Disk usage analyzer]

So I did a little clean to the /home folder, I deleted around 1GB of inutilities and my laptop is now going well. **BUT** I can't understand why the / size is wrong and so little... I think it's not normal and I want to resolve this annoying problem.
Can anybody help me? 
And... Can I resize the /home folder?

Here's my `df -h` output[image: df -h output]

And here's my `df -i` output

[image: df -i output]

Comment: Please add the output of `df -h` to your question.

Comment: I did it, thank you for the tip. Taking here a look I don't find something strange...

Comment: Everything looks good.

Comment: But what about the full root folder? It is not and I don't know where to touch :( I manually occupied about 70GB, it's not that big number...

Comment: _When and how_ does Ubuntu report that your file system is full? Can you add the precise message?

Comment: Well, the second screenshot talks, or not? Anyway I don't know in which case appeared that message to me, I had a BleachBit clean but nothing more... but the message was "Low disk space on <<filesystem root>>"

Comment: I don't see any "full root folder". You don't have a separate `/root` partition, and you file system is only 10% full.

Comment: @nplezka what do you think that the second screenshot says ? To me it looks correct .. 88.8 GC used in /, most of that in /home .. that's absolutely normal.

Comment: Had you, by any chance, accidentally put something in ` /root/.local/share/Trash/`?

Comment: @SorenA I thought I could fill my disk entirely without problems (well, not entirely, but not only 100GB over 1TB) with my documents, but the home directory (inode?) has a maximum capacity and I can't understand why and how to change size...

Comment: @Takkat no problems with /.local/share/Trash at all

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `df -i`

Comment: @SorenA updated.

Comment: @nplezka No problems there either, only used 1%.  Your root (/) filesystem is not full, and you should be able to use it up to almost 100%, 930 GB.

Comment: And why so Ubuntu told me it was full, it slowed down my pc (at least I removed only ~1GB to make it speed up) and the second screen tells /home and / are nearly full?  I'm going crazy haha

Comment: The second picture tells you that /home is using MOST space, 78.2 GB ... not that /home is full. You still have more than 780 GB free in /. You will have to find th exact situation, command and error when you get the full-message, before anyone can help you.

Comment: The output of `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 | grep "Reserved block count"` might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely ran BleachBit with a free space shredding.
When a file is deleted, it isn't actually removed from the disk, just the reference to the file is removed and the space is made available for use. Bleachbit and other utilities have a method to remove file remnants by overwriting them.

The process of erasing free space is to make a file and fill it with zeros until all disk space is used. Then the file is deleted. depending on security level chosen this may be done several times.

Considering the size of your HDD, it would have been quite sometime for the process to complete in the background.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [page](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/baobab-usage.html), the size that `Disk Analyzer` show to you is the currently allocated/used space, not the available space of your partition.

Therefore, you aren't running out of disk space, because `df` command and `gparted` show that you still have a lot of space.

---

As you can see in the following screenshot, it seems that also my `/` folder is full. However I assure you that I still have more than 100GB free in `/` partition.

[image: disk analyzer on my pc]

Instead of focusing on the graph, you should watch the main window that you get as soon as you open the tool. It shows you how much space you are using over the available space:

[image]